# Is it possible to buy a .sg domain with no affiliation to Singapore?

Tags: domains, country-codes

I am considering buying another domain for my site. Possibly wanting to buy .sg domains.  Is it possible to buy when my company is not in Singapore, and I am not Singaporean?

Comment: Why you want to buy sg tld name for your site and why you want that tld when you are not a Signaporean? Does your first website anyway related to Singapore?

Comment: Hi,
No, the company i work with is not in anyway related to Singapore, but it is situated pretty close to it.  I thought by having .sg domain name i would reach more customer and be better for SEO as well.

Comment: Is it bad for SEO to have multiple domain that points to your site? i am pretty new in this so it would be great to get all the help i can get.  Thanks

Comment: Choose a (dot)com. you can optimize for any country if you do better SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible.

Using a country code top-level domain could have negative implications for your website's SEO but you could always use a different domain as your primary domain and forward your .sg domain.

It shouldn't hurt your SEO to simply have another domain (unless it has spammy backlinks) but make sure to set it as a secondary domain and redirect traffic from the .sg to your primary domain.

I'm also curious why you want a .sg domain (I can't think of a domain hack that would end in sg).